# hyperref Warning: Token not allowed in a PDF string (PDFDocEncoding): removing `\@ifnextchar'

Tags: table-of-contents, hyperref, chapters, warnings

***Update*** - 12/28/2022
I have included below my MWE per @Miyase's comment. The error is coming from placement of `color{blue}` in line `\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter} ...` What to do to remove the `` Package hyperref Warning: Token not allowed in a PDF string (Unicode): removing `\@ifnextchar' `` message (**note**: now the error do not mention 'PDFDocEncoding' but 'Unicode')

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage[titletoc]{appendix}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage[hyperfootnotes=false,english,colorlinks]{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
  colorlinks=true,
  citecolor=PineGreen,
  linkcolor=red,
  urlcolor=blue}

% color the chapter headings in toc
\newcommand{\Chapter}[1]{\clearpage\thispagestyle{plain} % put new chapters on a new page
\refstepcounter{chapter} % manually increment the chapter number
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{{\color{blue}{{\bf Chapter \thechapter: #1}}}}
\noindent{\color{blue}\huge{{\bf Chapter \thechapter \hfill\break\newline\newline\newline \Huge #1}}\normalsize}
\vspace{10\baselineskip}
}

\begin{document}
    
\tableofcontents

\Chapter{Intro}

\Chapter{Test}


\begin{appendices}
\appendix

\chapter{Conclusions}
\end{appendices}
\end{document}
```

**Original post:**
Because I wanted a new font color and the word `Chapter \thechapter :` to appear in toc, I defined a new `\Chapter` command instead of the default `\chapter` in report class. But because of this, I get the following warning message:

`` Package hyperref Warning: Token not allowed in a PDF string (PDFDocEncoding): removing `\@ifnextchar' on input line 1. ``

Below is what I used to define `\Chapter` (This is the minimum working example because the error goes away if I do not use this):

```
\newcommand{\Chapter}[1]{\clearpage\thispagestyle{plain} % put new chapters on a new page
 \refstepcounter{chapter} % manually increment the chapter number
 \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\color{blue}{Chapter \thechapter : #1}}
\noindent \huge{\color{blue}{\bf Chapter \thechapter \newline\newline \Huge #1}} \normalsize
\vspace{1\baselineskip}
}
```

Comment: This is not a MWE, since this code isn't compilable. Please provide a MWE.

Comment: Not sure whether this question is still necessary, as [the solution I provide](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/669990/5764) solves your issue of manually creating a new chapter command/entry in the ToC.